# ¿Cómo seleccionar un texto en Word y convertirlo a fracción con vba?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Trato de seleccionar el texto en Word, por ejemplo:

```
10/8
18/6
12/4
```

Y con macros convertirlo a este tipo de fracciones con la línea horizontal:

[image: Fracción]

Me gustaría que se seleccionara todo ese texto y cada elemento se convirtiera así.

Tengo este código que lo que hace es pedirte mediante un cuadro de texto, la fracción:

```
Sub MakeFraction()
Dim Fraction As String, Numerator As String, Denominator As String
ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = True
With Selection
  ' For user input, you could use the following 2 lines to create a fraction
   Fraction = InputBox("Please input the Fraction (ex: 1/2, 5/32)")
   .Collapse (wdCollapseStart)
  ' Alternatively, to convert a selection, use the following line
  'Fraction = Trim(.Text)
  Numerator = Split(Fraction, "/")(0)
  Denominator = Split(Fraction, "/")(1)
  .Font.Size = Round(.Font.Size) / 2
  .Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
    PreserveFormatting:=False, Text:="EQ \f(" & Numerator & "," & Denominator & ")"
  .MoveLeft wdCharacter, 2
  .Delete
  .Fields.Update
End With
ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = False
End Sub
```

Pero en vez del `imput`, me gustaría implementar esto: `StrFrac = Split(Selection.Text, "/")`
¿Cómo lo podría hacer? De antemano agradezco mucho su apoyo. Saludos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para utilizar ese método de visualización tienes que utilizar OMath.

Te paso un ejemplo:

```
Sub EscribeFraccion()

    Dim objRango As Range
    Dim objEq As OMath
    Dim fraction As String
     
    fraction = InputBox("Please input the Fraction (ex: 1/2, 5/32)")
     
    Set objRango = Selection.Range
    objRango.Text = fraction
    Set objRango = Selection.OMaths.Add(objRango)
    Set objEq = objRango.OMaths(1)
    objEq.BuildUp
    
End Sub
```

Al objeto objRango tendrás que pasarle tu fracción para que la muestre como quieres.

Saludos.

Comment: Ok. funciona, pero solo lo hace para la información que has puesto en la macro. Por ejemplo, si quisiera hacerle esa fracción a un grupo de fracciones que tengo en un texto`6/4, 14/4, 18/4, 8/8, 10/4, 16/6` y **no** quiero que se modifique la información, por `"9/36"`, sino que todos y cada uno de esos elementos tomen ese formato de fracción. ¿Cómo lo haría?

Comment: He modificado el código para que veas un ejemplo tomando el valor que introduce el usuario en el inputbox. Si tienes grupos de fracciones tendrás que diferenciarlas de algún modo para poder convertirlas.

Si actualizas tu mensaje inicial y añades algún ejemplo tal vez podríamos ser más específicos.

Answer (score 3):

por si a alguien le llegase a servir, aquí dejo exactamente lo que necesité. Lo que hace la macro es seleccionar todas las fracciones de un textbox `2/3, 4/7, 9/3, 8/6, 2/5` y las convierte en stacked fraction de word.

```
Sub EscribeFraccionSel()
    With Selection.Range.Find
        .Text = "[0-9]@/[0-9]@"
        .MatchWildcards = True
        Do While .Execute
            .Parent.OMaths.Add(.Parent).OMaths(1).BuildUp
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]